# DSharpPlus How to create or set a discord channel to NSFW in C#

Tags: c#, discord, channel, dsharp+

PS: Sorry for my bad english, it not my first language

I'm creating a public discord bot with DSharpPlus in c#.
I know how to create channels(voice/text/category), set their roles/users permissions and figure out if a text channel is NSFW or not.

However, I don't know how to **create** a **NSFW** channel (or **make** a channel NSFW).

I was thinking that maybe it can be set with the class DiscordOverwrite, so I search in some documentations and found [DSharp​Plus.​Entities.DiscordOverwriteBuilder](https://dsharpplus.github.io/api/DSharpPlus.Entities.DiscordOverwriteBuilder.html), but the class doesn't exist in the DSharpPlus package that I have.

In conclusion, how do I make a NSFW text channel (with code and not manually)?

```
try
{
    var result = await ctx.Guild.CreateChannelAsync(sName, DSharpPlus.ChannelType.Text, null, null, null, new List<DiscordOverwrite>());
    await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"**Le salon NSFW '{result.Name}' à été créer**\n__Salon créer: {result.Mention}__").ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // Send error msg
    Util.SendMsg(ref ctx, Util.MessagesPreFaits.AucunSalonCréer, null, Util.EmbedType.Erreur);
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the nightly build in order to get the functionality: https://nuget.emzi0767.com/gallery/packages

Comment: Could you add a sample code to achieve what the asker was looking for using the package you suggested?

Comment: So, nightly build contain everything I need.

However,  CommandsNextModule.RegisterCommands<T>() and others fonctionnality of CommandsNextModule don't work.
[Image 1](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/765569804186026034/769229021874880572/unknown.png)
[Image 2](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/765569804186026034/769231538999001098/unknown.png)

It looks like the DSharpPlus (4.0.0-nightly-00743), doesn't content BaseModule or CommandsNextModule can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = await ctx.Guild.CreateChannelAsync(sName, DSharpPlus.ChannelType.Text, null, null, null, new List<DiscordOverwrite>(), true);
```

TIP: Hover over **CreateChannelAsync** to see all the available parameters.